# WooCommerce Conditional Tag inside plugin

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, conditional-tags

I'm writing a small plugin to add some text above the 'Add To Cart' button on the WooCommerce product page.

My code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'ddd_above_add_to_cart', 100);
function ddd_above_add_to_cart() { 
    if(is_product_category('vss') ) {
        echo 'hello world';
        }
}
```

My problem is when I use the conditional tag `is_product_category('vss')` to display the text based on the product category.
I'm sure this error is occurring as the function is not running inside the loop, but I'm not sure how to change this.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi Nathan Wilson, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (such as woocommerce) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. That said, I have seen woocommerce dev questions get good answers so it might work out. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thist function not working in product page

```
is_product_category()
```

So, for me the best options is first get the terms of the current post and the next step is get the name or slug, in this case i chose the category name

```
$product_cat_name = $term->name;
```

But you can chose the slug too (better option)

```
$product_cat_slug = $term->slug;
```

Here the documentation
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Example for Category name

```
/*Write here your own functions */
    add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'ddd_above_add_to_cart', 100);
    function ddd_above_add_to_cart() { 

            global $post;
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
            $nterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag'  );
            foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {
                $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
                $product_cat_name = $term->name;
                break;
            }      
           //compare current category name == any category name you want
            if($product_cat_name =='vss' ) {
                echo "This Work";
            }           
    }
```

Example for Category Slug

```
/*Write here your own functions */
    add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'ddd_above_add_to_cart', 100);
    function ddd_above_add_to_cart() { 

            global $post;
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
            $nterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag'  );
            foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {
                $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
                $product_cat_name = $term->name;
                $product_cat_slug = $term->slug;
                break;
            }      

            //compare current category slug == any category slug you want
            if($product_cat_slug =='any-slug-category' ) {
                echo "This Work";
            }           
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, works perfectly.

Comment: @metalbox - you can improve this answer by giving some explanation with your code, such as what is different and why. Just dropping in a snippet doesn't really [make a good answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @butlerblog ok, give me a few minutes

Comment: @butlerblog done

Comment: Wow - that was way, way better!  Good job!